# Understanding Conditional Mutual Information

Tags: information-theory

Recently I'm working on conditional mutual information and I'm trying to prove the following property:

```
I(X;Y|Z,W)<=I(X;Y|Z)
```

The property seems obvious to me: I(X;Y|Z) indicates "the reduction in the uncertainty of X due to knowledge of Y when Z is given"([1],section 2.5), so if we give more conditional variables, e.g. W, I(X;Y|Z,W) <= I(X;Y|Z). A demo is illustrated by the following figure.

[image: My interpretation of conditional mutual information]

My problem is: I'm not able to prove the above property and I don't know why.
Am I wrong with the interpretation of conditional mutual information? Or it's just I'm NOT able to do it?

Thanks a lot for anyone who helps.

Reference:

1. Cover,T. M. and J. A. Thomas (2012). Elements of information theory, Wiley-interscience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you prove $$I(U';V'|W) \leq I(U';V')\qquad(1)?$$ If yes, define
the distribution $P_{(U'(z),V'(z))}$ as that of $P_{(X,Y|Z=z)},$ 
and the distribution $P_{(U'(z),V'(z)|W)}$ as that of $P_{(X,Y|Z=z,W)}.$
For each $z$ apply (1)
in the form
$$I(X;Y|Z=z,W)=I(U'(z);V'(z)|W)\leq I(U'(z);V'(z))=I(X;Y|Z=z).
$$
Now take the leftmost term and the rightmost term with the inequality between them, multiply both sides by $P_Z(z)$ and sum over $z$ to obtain the result.

I find the venn diagrams to be confusing in this matter.

Comment: Hi kodlu,

Thanks for your help  but I don't understand your expression (1). because conditional mutual information $I(U;V|W)$  takes at least three variables.

If you mean $I(U;V) \geq I(U;V|W)$, then yes I can prove it.

Comment: @JiakaiXiao, please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The property seems false in general. Imagine $X = Y \mathrm{~XOR~} W$ (and $Z$ is irrelevant). Here $\mathrm{XOR}$ means the exclusive-OR gate. Then $I(X,Y | Z, W) = 1$ bit and $I(X, Y | Z) = 0$. See "interaction information" on Wikipedia for more examples.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. With a little participation on StackExchange you'll gain enough reputation to post comments on question, which would have been the appropriate place for this.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am indeed new and don't know much how it works. However, I don't see why it doesn't answer the question? If someone is trying to prove a property which is false, isn't giving a counter-example a response to the question?